# Creating user with password or changing password doesn't work in PostgresQL

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, database, postgresql, passwd

I'm trying to create a new user role or change existing one's password to be able to work locally with PostgresQL. I'm working on Ubuntu.

I can modify the attributes of an user, but for some reason it doesn't change the password. Here are the commands I've located from different instructions that to my knowledge should work.

```
 sudo -u postgres psql
 psql (9.3.4, server 9.2.5)
 postgres=# CREATE USER test WITH PASSWORD 'test123';
 CREATE ROLE
 postgres=# ALTER USER test SUPERUSER CREATEDB;
 ALTER ROLE
 postgres=# \du
                         List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
 -----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------     
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 test      | Superuser, Create DB                           | {}
```

After which I try to login using

```
 su - test
```

Which says

```
No passwd entry for user 'test'
```

If I try to change the password using

```
postgres=# ALTER USER test WITH PASSWORD 'test321';
ALTER ROLE
```

It still says

```
No passwd entry for user 'test'
```

I guess I'm missing something, but how could I fix this and be able to create users? Or am I doing everything terribly wrong :)

Thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the user doesn't actually exist. Try using `adduser test` to create the passwd entry

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize you actually needed that for Postgres as well... Well, got it working now, thanks :)